# Return value from match to Err(e)

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write a simple TCP echo server in Rust, and I'm a little confused over how to return a value from a match to Err.

I know the return type is supposed to be `usize`, and I'd like to return a zero. In other languages, I would just `return 0;` but Rust doesn't let me. I've also tried `usize::Zero()`. I did get it to work by doing `let s:usize = 0; s` but that seems awfully silly and I imagine there would be a better way to do it.

```
let buffer_length =  match stream.read(&mut buffer) {
    Err(e) => {
         println!("Error reading from socket stream: {}", e);
         // what do i return here?
         // right now i just panic!
         // return 0;
    },
    Ok(buffer_length) => {
        stream.write(&buffer).unwrap();
        buffer_length
    },
};
```

I know I could also just not have the `match` return anything and consume `buffer_length` inside the `match` with a function call or something, but I'd prefer not to in this case.

What is the most idiomatic way to handle something like this?

Comment: It's not clear what your problem actually is.  "Return value from match to Err(e)" just doesn't make any sense, and everything you've described sounds like it *should* work.  Your best bet is to update the question including a minimal, compilable example of what you're trying and the output of the compiler.  Also, a clear indication of what *result* you're trying to get (what should happen after this "return") would help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The same way you "returned" `buffer_length` from inside the `Ok` arm, you can simply "return" a `0` from the `Err` arm by leaving the trailing expression without `return` or a semicolon.

`return` always returns from a function. If you want to get the value of an expression, there's nothing you need to do in Rust. This always happens automatically.

This works for the same reason your `let s = 0; s` workaround worked. All you did was insert a temporary variable, but you can also directly let the expression get forwarded to the outer expression.

```
let buffer_length = match stream.read(&mut buffer) {
    Err(e) => {
         println!("Error reading from socket stream: {}", e);
         0
    },
    Ok(buffer_length) => {
        stream.write(&buffer).unwrap();
        buffer_length
    },
};
```