# How to return a Result containing a serde_json::Value?

Tags: rust, serde

This is what I have, but I want to avoid using `unwrap` on my reqwest values:

```rust
extern crate base64;
extern crate reqwest;

use serde_json;

use serde_json::json;

pub fn perform_get(id: String) -> serde_json::value::Value {
    let client = reqwest::Client::builder().build().unwrap();

    let url = String::from("SomeURL");

    let res = client.get(&url).send().unwrap().text();

    let mut v = json!(null);
    match res {
        Ok(n) => {
            v = serde_json::from_str(&n).unwrap();
        }
        Err(r) => {
            println!("Something wrong happened {:?}", r);
        }
    }

    v
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hi there! i want the function above to return a result instead of a Serde value so I can handle the error in main!");
}
```

[Here is a link to a rust playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&code=extern%20crate%20base64%3B%0Aextern%20crate%20reqwest%3B%0A%0Ause%20serde_json%3B%0A%0A%0Ause%20serde_json%3A%3A%7Bjson%7D%3B%0A%0Apub%20fn%20perform_get(id%3A%20String)%20-%3E%20serde_json%3A%3Avalue%3A%3AValue%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20client%20%3D%20reqwest%3A%3AClient%3A%3Abuilder()%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.build()%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.unwrap()%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20%20url%20%3D%20String%3A%3Afrom(%22SomeURL%22)%3B%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20let%20res%20%3D%20client%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.get(%26url)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.send()%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.unwrap()%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.text()%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20v%20%3D%20json!(null)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20match%20res%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Ok(n)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20v%20%3D%20serde_json%3A%3Afrom_str(%26n).unwrap()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Err(r)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22Something%20wrong%20happened%20%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20r)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20v%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22Hi%20there!%20i%20want%20the%20function%20above%20to%20return%20a%20result%20instead%20of%20a%20Serde%20value%20so%20I%20can%20handle%20the%20error%20in%20main!%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%7D)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The kind smart folks over at Rust Discord helped me solve this one. (user noc)

```rust
extern crate base64;
extern crate reqwest;

pub fn get_jira_ticket() -> Result<serde_json::value::Value, reqwest::Error> {
    let client = reqwest::Client::builder().build().unwrap();

    let url = String::from("SomeURL");

    let res = client.get(&url).send().and_then(|mut r| r.json());

    res
}

fn main() {
    println!("This works");
}
```

The key part was this in the header for the return

```rust
-> Result<serde_json::value::Value, reqwest::Error>
```

And this here to actually return the data.

```
client.get(&url).send().and_then(|mut r| r.json());
```

Answer (score 6):

The official Rust book, [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/), is freely available online. It has an [entire chapter on using `Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html), explaining introductory topics such as the `Result` enum and how to use it.

> How to return a `Result` containing a `serde_json::Value`?

The same way you return a `Result` of *any* type; there's nothing special about `Value`:

```
use serde_json::json; // 1.0.38

pub fn ok_example() -> Result<serde_json::value::Value, i32> {
    Ok(json! { "success" })
}

pub fn err_example() -> Result<serde_json::value::Value, i32> {
    Err(42)
}
```

If you have a function that returns a `Result`, you can use the question mark operator (`?`) to exit early from a function on error, returning the error. This is a concise way to avoid `unwrap` or `expect`:

```
fn use_them() -> Result<(), i32> {
    let ok = ok_example()?;
    println!("{:?}", ok);

    let err = err_example()?;
    println!("{:?}", err); // Never executed, we always exit due to the `?`

    Ok(()) // Never executed
}
```

This is just a basic example.

Applied to your [MCVE](/help/mcve), it would look something like:

```
use reqwest; // 0.9.10
use serde_json::Value; // 1.0.38

type Error = Box<dyn std::error::Error>;

pub fn perform_get(_id: String) -> Result<Value, Error> {
    let client = reqwest::Client::builder().build()?;

    let url = String::from("SomeURL");

    let res = client.get(&url).send()?.text()?;

    let v = serde_json::from_str(&res)?;

    Ok(v)
}
```

Here, I'm using the *trait object* `Box<dyn std::error::Error>` to handle any kind of error (great for quick programs and examples). I then sprinkle `?` on every method that could fail (i.e. returns a `Result`) and end the function with an explicit `Ok` for the final value.

Note that the `panic` and the never-used `null` value can be removed with this style.

See also:

- [What is this question mark operator about?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42917566/155423)
- [Rust proper error handling (auto convert from one error type to another with question mark)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48430836/155423)
- [Rust return result error from fn](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45583246/155423)
- [Return value from match to Err(e)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33116457/155423)
- [What is the idiomatic way to handle/unwrap nested Result types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39805834/155423)

> better practice to return a `Result`

See also:

- [Should I avoid unwrap in production application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39477684/155423)

Answer (score 3):

If you are in the user side I would suggest to use [`Box<dyn std::error::Error>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html), this allow to return every type that implement [`Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html), `?` will convert the concrete error type to the dynamic boxed trait, this add a little overhead when there is an error but when error are not expected or really rare this is not a big deal.

```rust
use reqwest;

use serde_json::value::Value;
use std::error::Error;

fn perform_get(_id: String) -> Result<Value, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let client = reqwest::Client::builder().build()?;

    let url = String::from("SomeURL");

    let res = client.get(&url).send()?.text()?;

    let v = serde_json::from_str(&res)?;

    Ok(v)

    // last two line could be serde_json::from_str(&res).map_err(std::convert::Into::into)
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", perform_get("hello".to_string()));
}
```

This produce the following error:

```
Err(Error { kind: Url(RelativeUrlWithoutBase), url: None })
```